# Elastic search, search data as where like 'TEXT%'?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to find sentences or words that start with the characters I'm looking for, what should I do for it?

For example:

get the data list like this

```
automatic car
car
carpet
car accessories
car battery
cast
game cards
race car
```

When I search for the word "car", I find the following data.

```
car
car accessories
car battery
carpet
```

I find the following data when I search for the word "ca"

```
cast
car
car accessories
car battery
carpet
```

that is, I don't want him to search the whole sentence, I just want him to search for words that start with search characters.

To give an example with sql, I would like to make an equivalent search to where like 'car%'

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the [Wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "field_name": {
                "value": "ca*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you want to implement *autocomplete* like feature - read [Suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html) documentation

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has a feature called prefix query, that returns documents that contain a specific `prefix` in a provided field.Also `wildcard` should also work for you.

```
 GET /_search
 {
   "query": {
      "prefix" : { "your_index_field" : "car" }
    }
  }
```

**SEE MORE**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html#prefix-query-short-ex